# Emulate bluetooth keyboard with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm wondering if it is possible to use my windows phone 8 as a virtual keyboard and mouse (HID) for any device that has bluetooth support with out creating software to install on the receiving computer.

I basically want to use my phone as a wireless mouse and keyboard.
Going to be used for presentations and for controlling a media center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. AFAIK, the lowest level of bluetooth support in WP8 is RFCOMM (reference [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1716881-bluetooth-data-transfer-apis)) and [HID is at the same level so it is not currently possible to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373814/802203).

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop is running Windows 7-8 you can install Microsoft Garage (Mouse without Borders) and use your phone as a mouse and keyboard. This would require the installation of the software on your laptop though. Not entirely what you were looking for, but a step in the right direction.

Comment: This is surely an approximate enough solution. :)